# Orange3 as a standalone executable using PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, orange, python-standalone

I am working in an offline-environment, and am trying to deploy standalone Python-based applications with `PyInstaller`. I have been successful in all the previous pojects thus far, but for the latest one involving Orange3, I have the following problem.

I tried packaging Orange3 as a standalone executable with `PyInstaller` via the command `pyinstaller setup.py` (which does not work) as I could not find a `main` script.

Is there currently a way which I can package orange3 as a standalone program? If there are solution(s) with `PyInstaller` or other libraries, it will be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint of Orange3 is `Orange/canvas/__main__.py`. A `pyinstaller Orange/canvas/__main__.py` should work better.